# How can I tell if a virtual machine was shut down or saved gracefully?

Tags: virtualbox, backup

How can I tell from the command line if a specific virtual machine was shut down or saved gracefully?

A little bit of context: I need to make a backup of a VM but I want the backup to launch only if the VM was either shut down or saved and did that successfully as I do not want the backup script to save a broken VM.

Edit: I use VirtualBox, the host machine is a LinuxMint 20 and the client machine is a Windows 10.

Comment: Could you edit your post to add more information. What VM software are you using ? (VMWare, Hyper-V, ...). What OS is the host using ? What's your backup software (it might already have options to detect these things) ? Anything else you may think of that is necessary

Comment: Check the log that was created,  check the event logs on Windows, there is software that will backup VMs automatically instead of whatever you plan to do to backup VMs that will work much better than your plan.

Comment: The only way you can know this is to start the machine and check logs.   I see "improper shutdown" in my Windows 10 reliability history if it had a bad shutdown. No way do know after a shutdown until you restart and check.

Comment: @Silbee Just added more info. Thanks!